# How to check validation on two fields in a form?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls, django-validation

Need to add an image to the form either by entering a ***link*** to the image, **or** upload a ***file*** from your computer. *If no options were entered* when the form was submitted, *or both options were entered*, an error message should be displayed. And after successful loading, you should get to the image page.

**models.py:**

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Ссылка на изображение')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/%Y/%m/%d', width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height',
                              blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение')
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Ширина изображения')
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Высота изображения')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Актуальность изображения')
    created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата создания записи')
    updated = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата ред-ия записи')
```

**views.py:**

```
def add_picture(request):
    picture = Picture.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureCreateForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'add_picture.html', locals())
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка, проверьте данные')
    else:
        form = PictureCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'add_picture.html', locals())
```

**forms.py:** Here you need to define a method **clean**

```
class PictureCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('url', 'image')

def clean(self):

    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['url'] and cd['image']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Ошибка!')
    if not cd['url'] and not cd['image']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Ошибка!')
    return cd
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('add_picture/', views.add_picture, name='add_picture'),
    path('picture_detail/<int:id>/', views.picture_detail, name='picture_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **`clean(...)`** method of **`forms.ModelForm`** as

```
class PictureCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('url', 'image')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        url = cleaned_data.get("url")
        image = cleaned_data.get("url")

        # do your logic here
        # atlast
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: The condition under which no field is entered works. But what if two fields are entered?

Comment: Since the `clean()` method gives you the `url` and `image` value ***at the same time*** you can do the rest, can't you?

Comment: I cannot create a condition where two fields are left blank. At this time, you need to raise an error. That is, if **url** and **image** remain empty, then you need to call an error message.

Comment: Figured out! Thank you for your time ^^